# Javascript syntax for concatenating in URL

Tags: javascript, syntax

I can show orderB.id as table data. I want to use this value in the href, but I am struggling with syntax.

```
        var output = results.reduce(function (orderA, orderB){
            var row = "<tr>";
            row += "<td>" + orderB.name + "</td>";
            row += "<td>" + orderB.type + "</td>";
            row += "<td>" + orderB.id + "</td>";
            row += "<td><a href='/update/' + orderB.id + >Update</a></td>";
            return orderA + row;
        },"")
```

I have tried:

```
            row += "<td><a href='/update/' + orderB.id + >Update</a></td>";
            row += "<td><a href='/update/' + 'orderB.id' + >Update</a></td>";
            row += "<td><a href='/update/orderB.id' + >Update</a></td>";
```

These output:

1. /update/
2. /update/
3. /update/orderB.id

I want for example: /update/3

Comment: All of those lines are literal strings because they start with `"` and end with`"` with no break in between. End the literal string, insert the variable, and continue with the rest: `"<td><a href='/update/" + orderB.id + "'>Update</a></td>";` Your editor should make it *pretty clear* when you're writing a string and when you're using a variable.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you this worked a charm

Answer (score 2):

use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) :

```
row += `<td><a href="/update/${orderB.id}">Update</a></td>`;
```

or simply concat your variables with the htmml string like :

```
row += '<td><a href="/update/' + orderB.id + '">Update</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been suggested, template literals are a good way to go, but you have to be careful about just sticking strings together to create HTML -- if there are characters like `<`, `>`, or `&` there can be problems. I'd use Lodash and modify the answer given by another poster like this:

```
row += `<td><a href="/update/${_.escape(orderB.id)}">Update</a></td>`;
```